# Uable to use ReactDOM.render (Element type is invalid)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I am very new to reactjs (currently using expo) and I've been looking at https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/primary-components and I tried just copying the first example to see what would happen:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return <h1>Hello React Router</h1>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

And I get this error

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `ExpoRootComponent`.
```

So is there something I'm missing? Am I supposed to just use ReactDOM.render only on components? Any input would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you include the code for `ExpoRootComponent` in your question?

Comment: Are you using Expo? You don't want to be using `react-dom` for that, and you should only have to export your topmost React component from the `App.js` file in the root of your project.

Comment: So should I just get rid of reactDOM.render and change `function App` to `export (default) function App`?

Comment: Yes, if this is your root `App.js` file, remove the `reactDOM.render` call and just export the `App` component. `export default function App() { /* ... */ };`

Comment: Are you using react-native for a mobile device?

Comment: I plan on making this app for a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

As you are telling you are using Expo, Expo is used to build react-native app so you may have to tweak your code,
so you need to import registerRootComponent from the expo

import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';//add this in beginning

registerRootComponent(App); //add this to bottom of your code instead of using react-dom

or

in the terminal just use npm start(Your code is fine according to react standards).
Make sure in package.json file in Scripts use have added the correct file path to start.